# Unauthorized laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I try to use Laravel's access policies, however, I receive over and over and over and over again the same error and I do not see what I need to import and / or use in functions or models.

First I show you my AuthServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use App\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as 
ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
protected $policies = [
    User::class => UserPolicy::class,
];

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    //
}
}
```

Now my UserPolicy

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
 use HandlesAuthorization;


public function __construct()
{
    //
}

public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) 
{
    return $authUser === $user;
}
}
```

And finally the edit function of my UsersControllers

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;

public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize($user);

    return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
}
```

With my UpdateUserRequest with authorize

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$this->route('usuario')
    ];
}
}
```

When I try to access it always tells me that I do not have authorization, even if I modify the edit function of UserPolicy.

Comment: You have declared an `UpdateUserRequest` but don't use it in your controller action.

Comment: I did this and now I do not get an error, but it does not redirect me or continue executing code, it just leaves me in the same place where it is. Maybe atuhorize when doing the return take me out, but it is not supposed to be the only thing that should be returned?

Comment: Any errors? `$this->route('usuario')` looks suspiciously placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your authorization call is wrong. The first argument of the authorization method needs to be the action you are trying to authorize. So the correct code for authorization check would be:

```
$this->authorize('edit', $user);
```

You are using identity operator `===` for comparing the user models. Like `return $authUser === $user;`.

According to the php manual:

> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

However, the `$authUser` instance and `$user` instance are different instances of same model. Use the comparison operator `==`.

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.

Now your user policy method will be:

```
public function edit(User $authUser, User $user) {
    return $authUser == $user;
}
```

Comment: I do not see anything change in the execution of the code to add that.

Comment: Thanks you a lot ^^